# Help identifying this fossil

Tags: palaeontology, fossil

Found near alexandria mn [image]

[image]
enter image description here

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. Pictures of the ends and sides would be helpful. Standard practice for photos like this would be to take them with the tape measure off to one side so that you don't obscure relevant details. Beside MN (Monaco? Mongolia? Myanmar? Montana?), what sort of rock did you find it in? Are you sure it is a fossil and not a random concretion?

Comment: It was in a bunch of random rock and black dirt and minnesota i will get more pictures it is def not concrete though

Comment: Ah - [concretion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concretion) is a type of rock caused by minerals joining particles of sand etc together. They can form some pretty odd shapes.